# Proof for if f has a bounded first derivative on [a,b], then it has bounded first variation on [a,b]

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, bounded-variation

I want to mathematically prove the following statement:
"if $f(t)$ has a bounded first derivative on $[a,b]$, then it has bounded first variation on $[a,b]$."

- First order variation is defined as: 
  $$
  \lim_{\Vert p\Vert \to 0} \sum^{n-1}_{j=0}|\Delta f_j|
  $$

So far, I got:

Bounded first derivative hypothesis can be written as: 
$$
\left|\lim_{t_{j+1}\to t_j}\frac{f(t_{j+1})-f(t_j)}{t_{j+1}-t_j}\right|\leq M,
$$ 
where $M$ is a positive real number.

Again, it can be written as 
$$
\lim_{\Vert p\Vert\to 0}\left|\frac{\Delta f(t_{j})}{\Delta t_{j}}\right|\leq M,
$$ where $p$ is a partition of $[a,b]$ and $\Vert p\Vert$ is the mesh of the partition.

Now, the first variation:
$$
\lim_{\Vert p\Vert \to 0} \sum^{n-1}_{j=0}|\Delta f_j|=\lim_{\Vert p\Vert \to 0} \sum^{n-1}_{j=0}\left|\frac{\Delta f_j}{\Delta t_j}\right||\Delta t_j|\leq M\cdot\lim_{\Vert p\Vert \to 0} \sum^{n-1}_{j=0}|\Delta t_j|
$$

How should I proceed from here? How do I know that the limit in the last expression is bounded/zero? I am looking for a formal proof and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Never mind. I got the answer! The summation of $\Delta t_j$ is simply $b-a$.

Comment: You got the answer? Post the answer and accept it yourself.